# How can I ensure that my sshfs mounted drives stay connected as much as possible?

Tags: mount, fstab, sshfs

I have been trying to get this to work forever and ever and it's just past my ability now. I have read just about everything I can on this...and yet I can't resolve the issue. Here's the short story.  I need to mount remote drives on my local server.  I can make that work with no problem.  I run the following commands:

```
sshfs -o idmap=user sfurules@somedomain.com:/home/sfurules/files/folder_1 ~/folder_1
sshfs -o idmap=user sfurules@somedomain.com:/home/sfurules/files/folder_2 ~/folder_2
sshfs -o idmap=user sfurules@somedomain.com:/home/sfurules/files/folder_3 ~/folder_3
```

Bingo.  Works like magic.

**HOWEVER:**

The remote drive is on a server that I rent and is shared.  So, sometimes it is reset and the mount drops.  Or sometimes I reset my home server and the mount drops. Or my internet stops for a second (thanks Comcast)...or for whatever reason the connection is just not like, rock solid all the time.  That's ok, I can understand that this is not an ideal way to transfer information sometimes.  However, when the mount is up and running it's flawless for my needs.

So...what can I do to make sure that my server is automatically keeping those sshfs mounted remote directories connected as much as possible?  I currently have this ugly system where I use tasker on my phone and an ssh app with snippets to run automatically at set intervals and connect to my home server remotely, open the running screen (screen -R), run the commands, and then disconnect.

I have tried creating a bash script and running that with crontab, but for reasons I can't understand it doesn't work (noob scripting trigger alert):

```
#!/bin/sh

screen -R

sshfs -o idmap=user sfurules@somedomain.com:/home/sfurules/files/folder_1 ~/folder_1;

sshfs -o idmap=user sfurules@somedomain.com:/home/sfurules/files/folder_2 ~/folder_2;

sshfs -o idmap=user sfurules@somedomain.com:/home/sfurules/files/folder_3 ~/folder_3;

screen -D
```

I have tried adding things to fstab but honestly it feels like I'm just guessing at things and I am truly too dumb to make that work...

Any help would be appreciated. I'm at the end of my rope.

Answer (score 3):

You could try supplying the `reconnect` option to `sshfs` (that's if you haven't done so already!)

```
sshfs -o reconnect -o idmap=user ...
```

Interestingly, the `sshfs` man page is quite uncommunicative about this option, but it seems to do what you're after.  I myself have a remote drive mounted with `sshfs` on a Mac, a Linux laptop and an Android phone, and the connection seems quite robust on all --- it will quite reliably (by no means always but I'd say over 90% of cases) survive loss of connection, suspend/hibernate etc.

Hope this helps!